# Copy files from Google Compute Engine VM to Windows local host

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have been trying to download files from the Google Compute Engine VM (Debian) to my Windows local directory using the command recommended in the documentation:

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse example-instance:~/narnia ~/wardrobe
```

How do I specify local/destination directory given that windows file path is different from linux? Where linux is `~/wardrobe`, what is the Windows equivalent? Something like `C:\Users\username\wardrobe`?

I tried `gcloud compute scp --project="my-project-id" --zone="us-east1-b" --recurse example-instance:~/narnia 'C:\Users\username\wardrobe'` but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you get an error message? **it didn't work** is not a good problem description. Note: If you are running the CLI on Windows, you should use an SSH program. The CLI is a wrapper to launch putty.exe.  Download and install a good ssh tool such as Bitvise. Software tools such as Git also include scp.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (because it avoids working out how to specify the Windows file-system location) is to change to the correct folder on your Windows machine and then run the command:

```sh
cd c:\Users\username\wardrobe

gcloud compute scp \
--project="my-project-id" \
--zone="us-east1-b" \
--recurse \
  example-instance:~/narnia \
  .
```

Where `.` should represent the current (i.e. `c:\Users\username\wardrobe`) directory on the Windows machine.

I'm unable to access a Windows machine but (!) I've seen paths get translated to *nix format as e.g. `c/Users/username/wardrobe` replacing back- with forward-slashes and referencing the drive as a folder